# Can't Set UI Scaling Per Display in Gnome

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors

## Problem

I want to be able to have different interface scaling options set per monitor. Right now, I can only change values for all monitors.

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon (3rd Generation). I will greatly appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

## Current Settings

```
$ xdpyinfo | grep dots
resolution:    96x96 dots per inch

$ xrdb -query | grep dpi
Xft.dpi:    144

$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep DPI
[    18.258] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)

$ xrandr | grep -w connected
eDP1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 174mm
HDMI2 connected 2560x1080+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 798mm x 334mm

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.14.4
```

## Ideal for Laptop

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
0.75
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides
{'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gdk/WindowScalingFactor': <2>}
```

## Ideal for External Monitor

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor
0.5
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides
{'Gtk/ShellShowsAppMenu': <0>, 'Gdk/WindowScalingFactor': <1>}
```

## I Tried

### xrandr scale

```
$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --scale 2x2
```

This seemed like a good result, but the screen lagged hard. It's unusable.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: I am not. I never found a solution and don't use linux much these days.